# Memcached set number attributes

Tags: memcached

Storing a key:value into memcached returns `set namespace:key_name 0 1209600 673`

What do 0, 1209600, and 673 mean? Looked around but couldn't find what it means. Appreciate if someone can point me to the docs or elaborate here, thanks!

Comment: That's a snippet of memcached text wire protocol.  This is generally the first google result for "protocol.txt" if you're really wanting to delve into it.  No API I know of should be returning that, though you didn't say which API you're using.

Comment: it's just right off the command line with memcached -vv option

Comment: OK, that's not "returning" that's "logging commands when run in verbose mode."  If you want to run in ultra verbose mode and see the commands it's running in that level of detail, you probably just want to read [the protocol docs](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) to understand what everything does.